# How to send email with Excel when date in column equal or smaller than today's date?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have three columns: A) Enterprises B) Email address matching the enterprise C) Yes or No

If there is a YES in column C, I want to send a message to the email address in column B.

This is what I have. Nothing is happening.

```
Sub Test2()

    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    On Error GoTo cleanup
    For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
          LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value) = "yes" _
          And LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value) <> "send" Then

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Reminder"
                .Body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
                  & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                  "Please contact us to discuss bringing " & _
                  "your account up to date."
                Attachments.Add ("\\C:\test.pdf")
                .Send  '
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value = "send"
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look at the questions under "related" on this page, try somethings out, then post back with your code if you run into a specific problem.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you. Here you go.  This is what I used so far. thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Comment out the `On Error` lines and then what happens when you run it?

Comment: `Attachments.Add ("\\C:\test.pdf")` missing the leading `.` to bind this to the `With OutMail` and the file path looks wrong.

Comment: @TimWilliams this path is just an example // Also, nothings happen when I comment out the '''on error''' lines

Comment: If nothing happens then your `If` tests are not passing for any of your data.  Add `OutApp.Visible  = True` if outlook isn't already open and visible

Comment: @TimWilliams Where do I add it? When I add ```OutApp.Visible = True``` it gives me a debugging error. The thing is, in EXCEL, in column D, I can see the words ''SEND'' when theres a ''YES''. But nothing actually happening in my Outlook ...

Comment: If Outlook is already visible then you don't need to add the Visible = True: just wanted to make sure Outlook wasn't hidden and giving you errors you couldn't see....   Still seems like your loop is not firing  - try putting some breakpoints or Debug.Print statements and see what's going on.

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm curious to know how this code will send a message ? I have 3 differet email adresses connected to my Outlook. How will it know which one to use? Nothing in the code precise my email adress.  Anyway thanks for the help

Comment: I have no idea how that would work: I only have a single address

Answer (score 0):

The code below will loop through Row 2 to the last row in the UsedRange and make sure that Columns A, B & C are not empty as well as check to make sure Column D is empty, which the code uses as a flag to show whether the email has previously been sent.

I've added a Regex validation function to the code to validate the email address.

```
Sub LoopThroughRange_SendEmail()
Dim OutApp As Object: Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim OutMail As Object: Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Dim oRegEx As Object
Set oRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with

For i = 2 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
'loop from Row 2 To Last Row in UsedRange
    If ws.Cells(i, "A").Value <> "" And ws.Cells(i, "B").Value <> "" And ws.Cells(i, "C").Value = "Yes" And ws.Cells(i, "D").Value = "" Then
    ' make sure that Columns A, B & C are not empty and D is empty (which we will use as a flag to show that the email did get sent.
        If ValidEmail(ws.Cells(i, "B").Value, oRegEx) Then
            With OutMail
                .To = ws.Cells(i, "B").Value
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "Reminder"
                .Body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
                          & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                            "Please contact us to discuss bringing " & _
                            "your account up to date."
                .Attachments.Add ("\\C:\test.pdf")
                .Display '.Send
            End With
            ws.Cells(i, "D").Value = "Sent @ " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
        Else
            ws.Cells(i, "D").Value = "Email not valid"
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Function ValidEmail(pAddress As String, ByRef oRegEx As Object) As Boolean
    With oRegEx
        .Pattern = "^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.\']+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)(\s*;\s*|\s*$))+$" 'pattern for multiple email addresses included
        ValidEmail = .test(pAddress)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: it gives me ''error compilation'' There's a 'FOR' without 'NEXT'

Comment: ```If Validemail``` is not working... it's giving me a debugging error

Comment: @MelanieDeschne sorry I've now updated the code, should be working, please try again...